# While trying to call another feature using dynamic array throws error as org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException:

Tags: karate

The below is the code

- def response = ['val1','val2']
- def myKeys = response.map(function(obj){ return obj.key })
- def callExtTest =
  """
  function(key) {
  var myEncodedKey = karate.urlEncode(key);
  var myFinalUrl = url.replace('{key}', myEncodedKey);
  var result = karate.call(read('test.feature'), { myUrl: myFinalUrl });
  results.add(result);
  }
  """
- karate.forEach(myKeys, callExtTest) but it throws error as below

rg.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (call) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@761ac53 failed due to: no applicable overload found (overloads: [Method[public java.lang.Object
com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(java.lang.String)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(boolean,java.lang.String,org.graalvm.polyglot.Value)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(java.lang.String,org.graalvm.polyglot.Value)], Method[public java.lang.Object com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.call(boolean,java.lang.String)]],
arguments: [JavaObject[classpath:features/filename.feature (com.intuit.karate.core.Feature)] (HostObject), DynamicObject@68b0e5ec (DefaultLayout)])

- .:anonymous(Unnamed:4)

Comment: sorry, this is the kind of issue that needs you to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be similar to the issue I was facing in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/133951688?noredirect=1)

try adding the boolean for sharedScope in the call function rather than read

```
var result = karate.call(true, 'test.feature', { myUrl: myFinalUrl });
```